# Create table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'am new to mysql and i want to know what KEY (not primary key) means in the query below :

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `username` varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `activation` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `idx_name` (`name`),
  KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=65 ;
```

also this line `ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=65 ;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A KEY is an index: it's just like a library index: quicker finding for the values of that colum. You want this for joining and searching.

```
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Means the engine you use (this is the default). If you need foreign keys for example, then you might want InnoDB.

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Is the default character set.

```
AUTO_INCREMENT=65 ;
```

Means that currently the auto-increment value is at 65.

Comment: @Bobj-C: _"Means that currently the auto-increment value is at 65"_ and so next time you insert a record using NULL for key, new index  will be 66.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 0):

`KEY` is a synonym for `INDEX`. See [database index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29) if you're not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX.

```
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

It means the storage engine for your table. There are two types of storage engines in MySQL: transactional and non-transactional. The default engine is InnoDB as of MySQL 5.5.5 ( MyISAM before 5.5.5).

```
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Character set support that enables you to store data using a variety of character sets.

```
AUTO_INCREMENT=65
```

It means currently the value of auto_increment is 65 for primary key `id`.

More information:- 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html